# Possible incompatibility between babel, listings and biblatex causes problem with unbreakable space in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, listings, babel

The following example compiles with an error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{listings}%\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @Article{A1, title = {A b}}
    @Article{A2, title = {A~b}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

    A: \cite{A1}.\\
    B: \cite{A2}.\\

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> **l.23** Undefined control sequence.

Something probably causes the `~` character in bibliography entry to be confusing for LaTeX, as document with `\cite{A2}` commented out compiles with no errors.

[image: Result after removing <code>\cite{A2}</code>]

Either changing `\usepackage[english]{babel}` to `\usepackage{babel}`
or changing `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}` to `\usepackage{biblatex}`,
or removing `\usepackage{listings}` (which is necessary, but its application was removed from the MWE),
also causes the document to compile without errors, so there are four factors involved: all three of these packages together with the usage of tilde character in bibliography.

I cannot figure out the reason because this incompatibility, but resolving it would be quite useful for me.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Strange “Undefined control sequence” message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202614/134574).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Edit:

Recently (September 2019) `listings` was updated and this issue no longer exists.

---

As Ulrike Fischer said in the comments below, this is a bug in `listings`. The package uses `\lccode` to define types of character for later use. This `\lccode` trick uses `~` because it's the one standard active character in LaTeX. But `listings` "forgets" to reset this `\lccode` to the original value and then `` \the\lccode`~ `` remains equal to `122` (that of `z`).

To fix the problem you can reset the `\lccode` of `~` right after `listings` is loaded. Also, as [egreg found out here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202621/134574), the same issue happens with `\/`, so the same fix can be used for both:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lccode`~=0 % Fix for ~
\lccode`\/=0 % Fix for \/ (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202621/134574)
```

---

## Old answer:

The problem is actually unrelated to `biblatex`. The same error is raised by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\MakeLowercase{A~b}
\end{document}
```

and the error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<to be read again> az
                     b
l.12 \MakeLowercase{A~b}
```

This happens with `biblatex` because it uses `\MakeLowercase`.

The error is, I think, due to some incompatibility caused by the interaction of `babel` and `listings`.

Apparently the `\lccode` of `~` is defined to `z` and this `z` is undefined. A workaround (not sure if the best alternative) is to make this definition:

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`z\lowercase{\endgroup\let~= }
```

then your MWE works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{listings}%\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @Article{A1, title = {A b}}
    @Article{A2, title = {A~b}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`z\lowercase{\endgroup\let~= }

\begin{document}

    A: \cite{A1}.\\
    B: \cite{A2}.\\

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: babel redefines ~, that's why it clashes with it. Beside this it is a bug in listings, and one should remind the maintainer to fix it (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302437/textcase-listings-and-tilde).