# Spacing issue with literate in listings

Tags: spacing, listings, bugs

I answered [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445687/134574) and OP showed me a problem with the answer. The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  % keepspaces, % Apparently this works...
  literate=
    {à}{{\`a}}1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
  Adicionar v à lista.
  Adicionar $v$ à lista.
  Adicionar $v$ onde?
  R: à lista.
  Yoda style: à lista, $v$ adicionar.
  Adicionar $v$ à lista e à outra lista.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

prints:

> [image]

and the space after the `à` is eaten.

From the four examples above, I concluded that the problem is isolated at the first `literate`d character in lines after `mathescape`d text.

- The second and sixth lines show the issue.
- The fourth line shows that the effect from the third line stops after the line break.
- The fifth line shows that the effect starts only after the `mathescape`d text
- The sixth line shows that the problem does not propagate to the following `literate`d characters.

Using the `keepspaces` option apparently solves the problem.

From the look of it I *think* it's a bug. How to fix this?

---

I also concluded that `v` was definitely added to the list :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*(August 12, 2018—it's Sunday and I don't have the nerve for delving deeply into the [source code of the **listings** package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.dtx).)*

But when skimming over that source code, I got the impression that

1. the macro underlying the replacement-process for the things provided via the `literate` key is called `\lst@Literate`.
2. there is a switch `\lst@ifwhitespace` which indicates whether the last processed thingie has been a space which has been printed as a whitespace.
3. the code of `\lst@Escape`—`\lst@Escape` seems to underlie all those thingies for escaping to LaTeX—does set that switch to false in case of being used due to `mathescape` being true. So with `mathescape=true` the switch is false after `$...$`. This leads to processing the space following `$...$` as whitespace which is not to be discarded but to be printed. This processing of the next space in turn leads to setting the switch to true again. Now the literate-thingie is processed. The underlying macro `\lst@Literate` does not set the switch to false. Thus due to the space before the literate-thingie being processesd as printed whitespace, the "machinery" after processing the literate-thingie still "thinks" that it has just processed and printed a whitespace and thus should discard following spaces.

This "thinking" of the machinery seems wrong in cases where the literate-thingie did as last item of output produce something other than whitespace .

What can be done about this?

Perhaps `\lst@Literate` should be redefined to set that switch to false.

Could look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  literate=
    {à}{{\`a}}1
}

\makeatletter
\def\lst@Literate#1#2#3{%
    \ifx\relax#2\@empty\else
        \lst@CArgX #1\relax\lst@CDef
            {}
            {\let\lst@next\@empty
             \lst@ifxliterate
                \lst@ifmode \let\lst@next\lst@CArgEmpty \fi
             \fi
             \ifx\lst@next\@empty
                 \ifx\lst@OutputBox\@gobble\else
                   \lst@XPrintToken \let\lst@scanmode\lst@scan@m
                   \lst@token{#2}\lst@length#3\relax
                   \lst@XPrintToken
                   \lst@whitespacefalse %!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                 \fi
                 \let\lst@next\lst@CArgEmptyGobble
             \fi
             \lst@next}%
            \@empty
        \expandafter\lst@Literate
    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
  Adicionar v à lista.
  Adicionar $v$ à lista.
  Adicionar $v$ onde?
  R: à lista.
  Yoda style: à lista, $v$ adicionar.
  Adicionar $v$ à lista e à outra lista.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*(Addition in August 18, 2018—it's Saturday and I still don't have the nerve for delving deeply into the [source code of the **listings** package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.dtx). ;-)  )*

But when doing so, we loose the possibility of having the `literate`-mechanism produce material whereafter a following space-token does not lead to producing more whitespace.

Thus perhaps it is better to just set the `\lst@whitespace`-switch to false within the `literate`-directive whenever that directive is used for having LaTeX typeset non-whitespace.

Could look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lstset{
  literate=
    {à}{{\`a\lst@whitespacefalse}}1
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
  Adicionar v à lista.
  Adicionar $v$ à lista.
  Adicionar $v$ onde?
  R: à lista.
  Yoda style: à lista, $v$ adicionar.
  Adicionar $v$ à lista e à outra lista.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I can absolutely not guarantee that my analysis of the situation is correct.
Maybe it is a starting point.

Seems that things work out correctly when

- either adding `\lst@whitespacefalse` to the definition of `\lst@Literate`
- or applying `\lst@whitespacefalse` inside the `literate`-directive.

Again: I can absolutely not guarantee that my analysis of the situation is correct.
Maybe it is a starting point.

In case setting `\lst@whitespacefalse` inside the `literate`-directive is to be considered good practice, both this should be mentioned somewhere in the manual, and for the end-user there should be a possibility of setting that switch without using `\makeatletter`..`\makeatother` beforehand.

In case you come to the same conclusion, feel free to hand in a bug report.  ;-)

Comment: For a Sunday, your answer is impressive! I tried (not very hard, I confess) to decipher this before asking the question, but failed... miserably. The code of `listings` is quite a thing to understand. Recently I mailed Jobst Hoffmann about [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443244/134574) and he answered. I'll try my luck again. Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, but you're contribution surely helped me!